# Get record from Xamarin.iOS in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, keychain

i need to get record from keychain via: `SecureStorage.GetAsync("xxx");`

In Xamarin.iOS app i have this:

```
 var s = new SecRecord(SecKind.GenericPassword)
            {
                Label = "Item Label",
                Description = "Item description",
                Account = "Account",
                Service = "Service",
                Comment = "Your comment here",
                ValueData = NSData.FromString("Something"),
                Generic = NSData.FromString("foo")
            };



            var err = SecKeyChain.Add(s);
```

I tried make native iOS app and i can get from Keychain value of "Account", but no in Xamarin.Forms. Where Xamarin.forms store encrypted data please? Is possible to get(share) some values from iOS in Forms? For example FCM token from Firebase?

Iam new in Xamarin

Thank you for response

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/secure-storage

Comment: thank you, but data via SecureStorage.SetAsync("xxx") (your link) arent store in keychain or UserDefaults - i dont know where... and i need to share data between xamarin.ios and xamarin.forms

Comment: please read the docs - they are explicitly stored in KeyChain.  "KeyChain is used to store values securely on iOS devices. The SecRecord used to store the value has a Service value set to [YOUR-APP-BUNDLE-ID].xamarinessentials."

Comment: yes, thank you. I missed it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where Xamarin.forms store encrypted data

Essentials SecureStorage on iOS uses a `SecRecord` for storage under an Account name (alias) that is constructed via:

```
// Special Alias that is only used for Secure Storage. All others should use: Preferences.GetPrivatePreferencesSharedName
internal static readonly string Alias = $"{AppInfo.PackageName}.xamarinessentials";
```

re: https://github.com/xamarin/Essentials/tree/develop/Xamarin.Essentials/SecureStorage